# Wrong order of references when combining subequations with cleveref

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, subequations

Could you please help identify what its wrong with my code (see below)? It uses subequations and cleveref. The result is that some of the references appear in a wrong order.
What I get is (1.1a) and (1.2) (1.4) and (1.3b).
What I would expect is (1.1a) and (1.2) (1.3b) and (1.4).

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\newcommand{\creflastconjunction}{, and\nobreakspace}
\newcommand{\crefrangeconjunction}{--}
\crefdefaultlabelformat{{\it #2#1#3}}
\crefname{equation}{}{}
\crefname{enumi}{}{}
\crefformat{enumi}{#2#1#3}

\begin{document}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\section{}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
 \label{ref2}\\
 \label{ref3}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\begin{align}
 \label{ref1}
\end{align}
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
 \label{ref5}\\
 \label{ref6}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\begin{align}
 \label{ref7}
\end{align}
\cref{ref2,ref1}
\cref{ref6,ref7}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: Don't use the obsolete font command `\it`. Better use either `\textit{…}` or at least `{\itshape …}`.

Comment: Off-topic: Do you really need `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}`? Code at TeX.SX is always in UTF8 not ISO-Latin-1 and AFAIK the default of all more or less up-to-date LaTeX editors is also UTF8, same as LaTeX default for more than five years.

Comment: You are not telling us the expected order. So to be sure: Am I correct, that the expected order would be `(1.1a) and (1.2) (1.3b) and (1.4)` independent from the order of `ref2` and `ref1` resp. `ref6` and `ref7` in the argument or `\cref`? Or do you just want the order of the `ref…` in the arguments of `\cref`?

Comment: Assuming you want "1.3b" to be listed before "1.4" as a result of the second cross-referencing call, you need to change `\cref{ref6,ref7}` to `\cref{ref6,,ref7}`. (Note the double-comma construct.)

Comment: Many thanks for your responses. I have updated my post explaining my expectations.

Comment: Mico, I have just tried ,, but it leads to the same result as before,

Comment: @Ann - You're right. I can see nothing wrong with your code (although I'd recommend deleting `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}`). Oddly, the sorting problem vanishes if the instruction `\numberwithin{equation}{section}` is dropped. You may have come across a bug in the `cleveref` package.

Comment: Not quite what you asked but `zref-clever` does get this sorting right.

Comment: @Mico, indeed, I have noticed that as well about numberwithin. It does look like a bug. I will check that with imputenc.

Comment: @qusbrs, thank you, I will take a look at this package. But I would still prefer to use cleveref as it is more established.

Comment: @qusbrs, zref-clever produces the right order for me as well, so thank you for your hint.